# Send mail message in powershell with a reminder

Tags: email, powershell

In Outlook, you can flag a mail message and "attach" a reminder to it.

[image: mail reminder]

Is it possible to do that when I want to send a mail message in a PowerShell script?

It doesn't look like the cmdlet `Send-MailMessage` has a parameter that would fit that purpose...

**UPDATE**

It is possible to attach a reminder before sending an email. The question now is if that information gets stored in the mail itself and if so, how could I use this in a script.

[image]

Comment: This is a feature of Outlook - you can't incorporate that sort of information into a mail message itself. I doubt you can even set a reminder when sending an email via outlook, so it won't be possible in powershell

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in POSH, and I guess no-way if you use `Send-MailMessage`. You would have to hand craft and encode mail body yourself and imitate what Outlook does, basically re-implement functionality in PoSH.

But you can show reminder via Powershell irrespective of the mail so that you don't need Outlook at all. When you couple it with `Send-MailMessage` the end effect will be the same.

See this post about creating reminder message box for instance:
[How to make a messagebox appear at a specific time in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846692/how-to-make-a-messagebox-appear-at-a-specific-time-in-powershell)

I would use event, ScheduledTasks or PowershellJobs rather then loop to register reminder because your script will not hangout until reminder is fired.